# Unable to get value onchange from reactstrap switch input

Tags: reactjs, input, reactstrap

I have a reactstrap switch which should return true/ false onchange.
Problem is I'm unable to get the value onchange.
this is how im doing this

```
         <div className='form-switch'>
          <Input type='switch' defaultChecked={orginalChoice} id={1} 
            nChange={setUserSwitchChoice}
             />
           <Label className='form-check-label' for={''}>
            <span className='switch-icon-left'>
             <Check size={14} />
              </span>
            <span className='switch-icon-right'>
               <X size={14} />
              </span>
              </Label>
          </div>
```

when I check the `setUserSwitchChoice` on console it returns the data like this :

```
SyntheticBaseEvent {_reactName: 'onChange', _targetInst: null, type: 'change', nativeEvent: PointerEvent, target: input#1.form-check-input, …}
bubbles: true
cancelable: true
currentTarget: null
defaultPrevented: false
eventPhase: 3
isDefaultPrevented: ƒ functionThatReturnsFalse()
isPropagationStopped: ƒ functionThatReturnsFalse()
isTrusted: true
nativeEvent: PointerEvent {isTrusted: true, pointerId: 1, width: 1, height: 1, pressure: 0, …}
target: input#1.form-check-input
timeStamp: 553191.0999999996
type: "change"
_reactName: "onChange"
_targetInst: null
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

So please let me know how to get the correct value in boolean format like `true`, `false`.

```
onChange={(e) => setUserSwitchChoice(e) // also tried this but working
```

Comment: Try onChange={(e) => setUserSwitchChoice(e.target.value)}

Comment: it gives the value `on` , but not in bool

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve it. But what I most like making a handler for that purpose. So,
Make a handler to get the response onChange implementing the `useState`.

```
const [orginalChoice , setOrginalChoice ] = useState(orginalChoice) 
// handle accordingly as ur original state 
// originalChoice should be true or false.
```

Then, create a change handler like this:

```
const onChangeHandler = () => {
    if (orginalChoice === true) {
      setOrginalChoice(!orginalChoice) # that will reverse the true to false
    } else {
      setOrginalChoice(!orginalChoice) # that will reverse the false to true
    }
     // console.log(orginalChoice) // To check the data on console
  }
```

Finally, update the switch input code with submit handler like that

```
   <div className='form-switch'>
     <Input type='switch' defaultChecked={orginalChoice} id={1} 
       onChange={onChangeHandler}/>
      <Label className='form-check-label' for={''}>
        <span className='switch-icon-left'>
          <Check size={14} />
        </span>
        <span className='switch-icon-right'>
         <X size={14} />
         </span>
      </Label>
    </div>
```

Now this should return the value in bool. `true` / `false`

Comment: @atropabelladona check this out.